# Dynamic Linq Expression for IEnumerable<int>.contains(MemberExpression)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I want to create an expression using the Linq Expression tree to simulate this:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();

// Fill ids with data

db.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id));
```

This is where I have gotten, but I am still missing something:

```
MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(T).GetProperty(property));

Expression callContains = Expression.Call(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable), "Contains", new Type[] { me.Type }, me);
```

How can I do what I want to do properly?

Comment: I have just one question. Why would you want do something like this?

Comment: I am building a very large and very complex search mechanism using linq. The framework I have does not allow access to the IQueryable objects, only our custom models, so I can't just chain the queryables like I would normally. Instead, I am building the expression dynamically piece by piece depending on search options selected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `Contains` is an extension method, you'll also have to provide the `ids` collection as a parameter, in this case, as a `ConstantExpression`.

Your implementation might be slightly different, but it would look a bit like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> DynamicContains<T, TProperty>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, 
    string property, 
    IEnumerable<TProperty> items)
{
    var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var me = Expression.Property(pe, property);
    var ce = Expression.Constant(items); 
    var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { me.Type }, ce, me);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, pe);
    return query.Where(lambda);
}

db.DynamicContains("Id", ids);
```

Comment: I don't see the `property` argument is used anywhere in your method, I think you mean `typeof(T).GetProperty(property)` (instead of "Id").

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed, and I see what I was missing before.

Comment: Why don't you use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341554.aspx) of `Expression.Property` to make your 2nd line just `var me = Expression.Property(pe, property);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add reference to Mono.CSharp dll, then you can use Evaluator class to compile csharp codes on the fly
then concat strings to create linq queries easily
then compile them
it's not slow, and it is easy

Answer (score 0):

In complementary of @p-s-w-g answer, the Dynamic**Not**Contains is :

```
    public static IQueryable<T> DynamicNotContains<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> query, string property, IEnumerable<TProperty> items)
    {        
        var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var me = Expression.Property(pe, property);
        var ce = Expression.Constant(items);
        var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { me.Type }, ce, me);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(call), pe);

        return query.Where(lambda);
    }
db.DynamicNotContains("Id", ids);
```